# String regularization function not working within for loop in R

Tags: r, string, stringr, data-cleaning

I have 95 individual .csvs in a directory with information pertaining to public employees in 19 different municipalities. The datasets are mostly in the same structure, and mostly list data in the same format, but there are some outliers that I am looking to regularize. Later on in my analysis I want to do some matches using employee names, so regularizing that column will be the most important. The operations I am trying to perform are:

- rename columns in each dataset so they have the same conventions
- make all employee name columns first name first, last name last (most of the datasets are in the correct format, with no commas ([1,1] John H. Doe). The problematic ones will be something like [1,1] Doe, John H.)
- remove all punctuation
- remove suffixes (jr, ii, iii)
- remove middle initials
- trimws
- standardize the number of columns so they can be combined later (all datasets have the same first 11 columns in the same order and all columns past that in the other sets are not of interest to me)

To do this I've created this function:

```
library(stringr)
fixNames <- function(x){
    if(length(grep(",", x[1])) > 0){
    names <- as.character(x)
    names <- str_split(names, ",", simplify = TRUE)
    newNames <- paste(names[,2], names[,1], sep = " ")
    newNames <- tolower(newNames)
    newNames <- gsub("[.]", "", names)
    newNames <- gsub(" *\\b[[:alpha:]]{1}\\b *", " ", names)
    newNames <- gsub("\\s{2,}", " ", names)
    newNames <- gsub("*\\bii\\b", "", names)
    newNames <- gsub("*\\biii\\b", "", names)
    newNames <- gsub("*\\bjr\\b", "", names)
    newNames <- trimws(newNames, which="both")
    x <- newNames
    } else{
    names <- as.character(x)
    newNames <- tolower(names)
    newNames <- gsub("[.]", "", names)
    newNames <- gsub(" *\\b[[:alpha:]]{1}\\b *", " ", names)
    newNames <- gsub("\\s{2,}", " ", names)
    newNames <- gsub("*\\bii\\b", "", names)
    newNames <- gsub("*\\biii\\b", "", names)
    newNames <- gsub("*\\bjr\\b", "", names)
    newNames <- trimws(newNames, which="both")}
    x <- newNames
}
```

Then I implement the function with a series of for loops

```
## rename all employee.name columns and make them character vectors
for(i in 1:length(files)){
    ifelse(exists(files[i]) == TRUE, dinger <- get(files[i], envir = .GlobalEnv), dinger <- data.frame(matrix(NA, nrow = 0, ncol = 11)))
    dinger[,1] <- as.character(dinger[,1])
    colnames(dinger) <- c("employee.name","job.title", "base.pay", "overtime.pay", "other.pay", "total.benefits", "total.pay","total.pay.benefits", "year", "notes", "jurisdiction.name")
    dinger <- dinger[,c(1:11)]
    assign(files[i], dinger)
}

## fix names
for(i in 1:length(files)){
        index <- files[i] 
        dinger <- get(index, envir = .GlobalEnv)
        names <- as.data.frame(as.character(dinger$employee.name))
        dinger$employee.name <- apply(names, 2 fixNames)
        assign(files[i], dinger)
}
```

When I do that it pitches an error like this:

Error in `$<-.data.frame`(`*tmp*`, "employee.name", value = c("Till",  : 
  replacement has 384 rows, data has 192

Now I know that means that after the function splits the names and reorders them it is not putting them back together. The question is, why? Is it something to do with the for loop?

Comment: Can you provide a reproductible example ? A sample of your use case ?
(don't know if just typo in your SO post or in your code bu your missing a comma in the last lines : `dinger$employee.name <- apply(names, 2,  fixNames)`

Comment: Here's a few files that would be typical of what we're trying to clean up:


http://transparentcalifornia.com/export/san-diego-2011.csv
http://transparentcalifornia.com/export/san-diego-county-2012.csv
http://transparentcalifornia.com/export/oceanside-2013.csv